# How do I get back into being an MMA Journalist?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, mixed-martial-arts, boxing, kickboxing, ufc

First off I like to say I am an hardcore MMA fan. My name is Rouzbeh Karimkhani, I used to be a reporter for *Mixed Martial Arts In Canada*. I did this 15 years ago only as a passion. I would like to get back into being a reporter and coverage of the sport.

My Favourite fighters of all time. GSP, Chuck Liddell, Ken Shamrock, and a bunch of others. My favourite Martial Art Aspect is the boxing/striking .My question is how do I get back into this field I really would like to work for the major mma media companies.

In the past I have interviewed. Royce Gracie, Gsp, Rampage Jackson. I watch and study MMA like no other person, every aspect of the game. I had very strong confidence in my interview style when I did it 15 years ago.

I recently got my  degree in Radio, TV and Digital Broadcasting. I look up to guys like Ariel Helwani. I'm much older today and was curious how I can get a jump into the game of media coverage and how can I get a hold of the major outlets. Thank you for your time I hope someone can answer my question.

Comment: Maybe start a blog and use it to develop a folio of writing. You could start by covering local level events, and by later applying for press passes for bigger and bigger events. You would ideally demonstrate an ability to produce eloquent, knowledgeable, error-free material quickly. Initially you might consider taking your own photos, but using someone more experienced would allow you to focus more on your writing.

Comment: I don't understand how you, as a former professional, expect non-professionals to assist.

Comment: ^_^ Maybe he hopes some of us are professionals? Even if we're not professional MMA journalists, we might be professional MMA fighters slumming it out in here (or even semi-pro ones who make a little coin from fights from time to time).

Comment: This is a very hard gig, as many are already doing it. but don't give up and go after your dreams

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is not a subject area in which I have any experience. My naive first thoughts would be to google MMA web sites and then send them introduction letters asking if they were interested in hiring you for field reporting. But that's kind of a shot in the dark.

You could also check out LinkedIn and network there with people you know in the business. That's always a good idea. Especially try writing articles there and see if anyone in your network likes on it or comments. Keep track of those people, and then later on you can message them or tag them on articles asking if anyone could use your talents.

That's just the most obvious sort of things you can do. And it applies to pretty much any career.

Beyond the obvious, if I was in a similar position, I think my approach would be to start Liking on different MMA posts on Facebook. Facebook's algorithm will then start serving you with more and more MMA material. As you get these, look at the Like counts of each post and write them down. Keep track of each organization's Like counts. After a short while (probably just a couple weeks to a month), the major players will likely be obvious. Those would be the ones with the most Likes. You'll want to go to them and offer your services. They probably have the most ad revenue and can actually pay you.

They're going to want to see your work. Have that ready to go. But mostly these guys are going to want to know how many Likes you're going to bring to them. That translates to ad revenue for them. If you have anything on social media already that they can look at which has high Like counts, you're good to go. That's all they need to see.

If you don't have that yet, then you'll want to see if you can get that started and promote yourself. You can do a Youtube channel or setup an Instagram account. If you can get enough Likes and subscribers, you can start making money on your own. You can purchase Facebook ads. You can of course send links to everyone you know and ask them to Like on your stuff and send it to everyone they know.

That's kind of how I think this game is played today on social media. I could be way off. But I figured I'd at least toss in my 2 cents on the subject. If you can locate someone in the business to mentor you, that would be ideal. Good luck!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Contact the media show them your past work, interviews and see if they want to hire is probably the best way to go. I myself am a hardcore fan and I seen your past interviews great job keep at it

Comment: Why are you complimenting yourself?